# Get all numbers between all HTML tags with regex

Tags: regex

I have a HTML code like this:

```
<div style="font-size:15px;">This is test number 55</div>
<span class="max5">Your number is: 5599</span>
```

I want to get all numbers between HTML tags that must be `55` and `5599`, I try these patterns but no luck:

First:

```
<\s*[a-z][^>]*>(\d+)<\s*/\s*[a-z]>
```

Then:

```
\>(\d*)\<
```

Comment: Can't you use a DOM parser instead? Would seem more appropriate.

Comment: Strip all tags first. Then search for the numbers you want.

Comment: What Regex flavor are you using? I think your `/` token would throw a syntax error in most.

Comment: @Jeto It must be a regex.

Comment: @sln The numbers will be replaced by something else, then I can't strip tags.

Comment: Strip all tags https://regex101.com/r/NsR6Pa/1 then find the number you want.

Comment: Or should you require more content info up to the number, it's just this https://regex101.com/r/BL3e8m/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* cannot use anything but a regex, this should work in most cases:

`/\d+(?![^<]*>)/g`

**Demo**: https://regex101.com/r/b71t0r/1 (PHP regex here, but should work with all popular engines)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
/<(\w+)[^>]*?>(.*?)<\/\1>/g
```

It starts by matching a start tag, then captures the name of that tag '`(\w+)`'in `Group 1`, then matches any char up to a '`>`', any number of times, then creates a `Group 2` with any number of any char, before it matches '`</`' followed by the tagname from `Group 1` '\1'.

Your wanted output will be in `Group 2.`

Note, this will not Work with nested tags.